# Sharing data between controllers and dealing with update/change notifications

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

I'm trying to get my head around sharing data between multiple controllers, but couldn't find out yet how this is supposed to work (the angular way). I have create a Data service that look something like this:

```
angular.module('myapp.services')
  .service('DataSet', function($rootScope) {

  return {

    filter: function(filterMethod) {
      /// ... do async stuff
      $rootScope.$broadcast("Data::filtered");
    },

    brush: function(brushed) {
      /// ... do async stuff
      $rootScope.$broadcast("Data::brushed");
    },

    load: function() {
      /// ... do async stuff
      $rootScope.$broadcast("Data::loaded");
    }
  };
});
```

Next I want to reuse and update data from this service, so I use it in my controller as follows:

```
angular.module('myapp.controllers')
  .controller('FilterCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, DataSet) {

  $scope.safeApply = function(fn) {
    var phase = this.$root.$$phase;
    if(phase == '$apply' || phase == '$digest') {
      if(fn && (typeof(fn) === 'function')) {
        fn();
      }
    } else {
      this.$apply(fn);
    }
  };

  function updateBrushed() {
    $scope.safeApply(function() {
      $scope.brushed = DataSet.brushed;
    });
  };

  $scope.brushed = [];

  $scope.keepSelected = function() {
    DataSet.filter(DataSet.FilterMethod.KEEP);
  };

  $scope.removeSelected = function() {
    DataSet.filter(DataSet.FilterMethod.REMOVE);
  };

  $scope.$on('Data::brushed', updateBrushed);
  $scope.$on('Data::filtered', updateBrushed);
});
```

The problem I have is basically illustrated by the use of the saveApply call. Basically I got this code from here: https://coderwall.com/p/ngisma. What I don't understand though is why I need it. As far as I can see, I'm 'within' $angular when updating the DataSet service. Nevertheless, the view for the Filter controller doesn't get updated without a call to saveApply ($apply doesn't work at all because than I run into the apply already in progress issue).

So, basically my question boils down to: is the approach above a good way to share data, and if so how is notification of changes in the service supposed to work?

**Update:** Based on Julian Hollman his suggestion I came to the following solution: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljfadvru/7/. This more or less illustrates the full workflow I was working on, though some of it is automatically induced in the fiddle, as opposed to user-interaction based in my real application. What I like about this approach is that it only sends signals when all data is updated.

Working with references, as suggested by Ed Hinchliffe, is nice as well. However, I'm working on a web visualization framework and I'm expecting tens of thousands of items. Clearing arrays and pushing new elements (which seem to me the consequence of this proposal) is really not feasible (if I understand this paradigm well, it would also result in a re-rendering of my vis for every single change). I stand corrected though if there are suggestions for further improvement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$broadcast` doesn't trigger an `$apply` and I bet your "async stuff" is not $http from angular.
So something happens outside of angular and angular doesn't know that something has changed.

In my opinion the best thing in that case is to write a wrapper for your async code and trigger $apply after date came back from the backend. Don't do it in the controller.

Comment: Actually the async stuff **is** $http from angular in this specific case. The broadcast is called from the success function of an $http request. Anyhow, that doesn't seem to make any difference as broadcast isn't triggering an apply. So, should I use a different "broadcast" method, or otherwise, how would this wrapper code look like?

Comment: Please see my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ljfadvru/1/
This should be your case in a simple form, right?

Comment: That comes close indeed. Does that fiddle actually work for you? It shows me briefly the initial data but not the new data.

Comment: Yep, that works, it was the e(vent) argument that was missign, no? I'll check this out tomorrow to see if this approach fixes my problem.

Answer (score 1):

To be honest, I'm not sure quite sure about exactly what is going on with the digest loops in your particular scenario, but I don't think you are approaching this the right way.

The 'angular' way, is to use promises.

Your service should be more like this:

```
angular.module('myapp.services')
  .service('DataSet', function($rootScope) {
  return {
    filter: function(filterMethod) {
      var returnData = []
      $http.get('/some/stuff').then(function(data){
        for(i in data){
          returnData.push(data[i]);
        }
      });
      return returnData;
    }
  };
});
```

This sets up an empty placeholder object (`returnData`) that can be immediately passed to the controller, but a reference is kept so that when the data returns you can retrospectively populate that object. Because the controller and the service reference the same object, it'll 'just work'.

This way you don't have to worry about dealing with `$digest` or `$apply` or `$broadcast`.

You controller can just call `$scope.filtered = DataSet.filter();`

**EDIT**

If you want to be able to access the exact same data from multiple controllers:

```
angular.module('myapp.services')
  .factory('DataSet', function($http) {

  var cache = {
    filtered: []
  }

  return {
    getFiltered: function(){
      if(cache.filtered.length) return cache.filtered;
      $http.get('/some/url/').then(function(data){
        for(i in data){
          cache.filtered.push(data[i]);
        }
      });
    }
  };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately in that you case you only get the reference to returnData where you requested the data.

Comment: That only works when only one Ctrl is accessing filtered data. What if there is another controller that needs to get updated when the data is filtered as well? You can't get around broadcasting then, can you?

Comment: Additionally, I'm expecting large numbers of items in the data (~80k) and I preferably only do an update once everything is in, at one go.

Comment: You can use a similar approach, but just have to be a bit more clever about how you cache the data.

Comment: You can of course still use `$broadcast` if that's how you prefer to think.